# Split up text using strsplit

Tags: r, strsplit

I am trying to split up a text file into a list using `R`'s `strsplit()`.
The separator is the HTML tag `<HR style="margin-bottom:0pt;">`. 
For some reason however, I can't seem to be getting the expression right, with which to split up the text.

```r
text <- readr::read_file("https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/904333/000119312518283722/d599396dnq.htm")
split <- strsplit(text, split = "\\<HR style\\=\"margin\\-bottom\\:0pt\\;\"\\>")
str(split)
#> List of 1
#>  $ : chr "<DOCUMENT>\n<TYPE>N-Q\n<SEQUENCE>1\n<FILENAME>d599396dnq.htm\n<DESCRIPTION>N-Q\n<TEXT>\n<HTML><HEAD>\n<TITLE>N-"| __truncated__
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Any ideas on what needs to be fixed here?

Comment: Just use a fixed string rather than a regular expression. Looks like you were doing a bit too much escaping: `split <- strsplit(text, split = "<HR style=\"margin-bottom:0pt;\">", fixed=TRUE)`

Comment: Ooooh that was super useful! Thank you so much!

Comment: There is also `stringr::str_split`